# How to do profiling a C++ project with gprof?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, profiling, gprof

I have a big C++ program in VS code under Ubuntu 18.4, I am using CMake. I need to Know what areas are spending more time and memory space. I am a beginner in coding in Linux and using CMakeLists.txt files. I tried to use gprof, I added

```
if(MSVC AND MT)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /MT")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /MTd")
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE} /MT")
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG} /MTd")
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pg")
    SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -pg")
    SET(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} -pg")
endif()
```

to my CMakeLists.txt file. Then I complied the program using `cmake ..` and then `make`, after that I run the program with an example, and when using the command `gprof ./myexe` I get `gmon.out: No such file or directory`

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ benchmark" or "C++ profile".  Always search the internet first.

Comment: Recommend adding which tool chain you are using to narrow down the question.

Comment: @user4581301 I added `SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pg")
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -pg")
SET(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} -pg")`  to my `CMakeLists.txt` file. Then I complied the program using `cmake ..` and then `make`, after that I run the program with an example, and when using the command `gprof ./myexe` I get  `gmon.out: No such file or directory`

Comment: That should be in the question. It answers my question, the tool is `gprof`, and will make the question more meaningful.  Also change the title to highlight that you are using `gprof` and getting an error; It's more specific and more likely to attract the attention of a `gprof` expert. JUst as important, it'll make the question easier to find for future askers.  But before you go too much further, have you done a websearch for `gmon.out: No such file or directory`? Five bucks says you're not the first or last person to struggle with this.

Comment: @user4581301 I did not specify gprof in my question because I wanted suggestions for suitable profilers in VS  code, but I will edit my questions to at least start profiling.

Comment: See if valgrind's callgrind tool is of use to you. Google has (or at least had) a profiler but I can't remember the name exactly. perftool should be close, but it's from google so there'll be a g in the name somewhere.

Comment: See also [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: [*Don't*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771)